# How to update fields in a table and insert it into new table with out updating the old table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am working on java with JDBC connections and trying to perform DDL commands.
Here i had a doubt about one particular flow, can that be possible? if yes, can you explain me how and what to do with example.

I am trying to **select** data from item table containing item_id, sale_price, description, barcode columns and want to update **barcode** data for **item_id = 9** and **insert** into **item_duplicate** table. With out updating the **item** table. But **item_dupliacte** table should **contain** the **updated** **value** for barcode.

[my item_duplicate table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akxyj.png)

[item table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0XE4.png)

```
MERGE item_duplicate AS D  
USING item AS I
ON  (D.item_id = I.item_id )
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE set D.part_no='new part'                     
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY D
THEN 
INSERT (item_id,part_no,sale_price,description,barcode) 
 SELECT i.ITEM_ID,i.PART_NO,i.SALE_PRICE,i.DESCRIPTION,b.BARCODE
 FROM item i 
JOIN item_barcode b
 ON b.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID 
WHERE i.ITEM_ID = ? 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY I
THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: can you please provide sample data and expected output? so that we can help you much better. Thank you.

Comment: @SirchDcmp I attached my table descriptions in question. Now what I want to achieve is retrieve the data from item and insert it into item_duplicate only specified columns in item_duplicate. along with this if user asks for updating the value of particular field I need to update that value in item_duplicate table while retrieving from item table with out change in item table values.

Comment: if my user asked for update in part_no field then the data provided by the user to update must be replaced by old data only in item_duplicate table the data in the item table should not be changed.   Thank you.

Comment: You cant get the answer if the way you ask is like this, remember, this is not a free code service, where's the fiddle so we can help you? where are your expected results? where's your sample data? what have you tried so far to solve your own problem? please considering this if you want to us to help you out

Comment: Thank you @18Man I updated question with query I tried but I am getting error in output as Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

A simple insert into select from.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST
(
      item_id     INT NOT NULL
    , barcode     VARCHAR (20) NULL
    , sale_price  DECIMAL (14, 2) NULL
    , description VARCHAR (100) NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_COPY
(
      item_id     INT NOT NULL
    , barcode     VARCHAR (20) NULL
    , sale_price  DECIMAL (14, 2) NULL
    , description VARCHAR (100) NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
)


INSERT INTO TEST_COPY (item_id, barcode, sale_price, description)  SELECT item_id, '9999' as barcode, sale_price, description FROM TEST WHERE item_id = 9
```